# die() or exit() without destructors?

Tags: php, exit, die

I would like to stop my php code when a condition is not valid.

Example:

```
if (strlen($string) < 6){   

 echo "minimum 6"

}   

if (strlen($string) > 32){   

echo "maximum 32"

}   

echo "success"
```

i would like stop the php code if the first condition is not met that it stops the script (so that it does not display success)

if I use die or exit it deletes the whole page, I just want to stop the script and leave the page as it is...

Comment: If you specifically don't want to show "success" then just move `echo "success"` inside the `if`. But die() will stop the script at that point, if that's what you want. Anything that's already been output will still be shown on the page.

Comment: Die or exit doesn't delete anything, if you mean that it stops processing the page at the point you killed it then yes that what killing it does

Comment: the reason for what? Session start just lets you access the session, nothing else

Comment: You may use `return ;` to stop process in that (page, class::method, function). It will not kill process. The process can still continue if you call this (`include`) from another page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`die` and `exit` are PHP keywords that cause the code to cease execution immediately

```
<div>
<?php
echo "123";
exit();
echo "456"
?>
</div>
```

so this code will do the following

```
add "<div>" to the output buffer 
add "123" to the output buffer
kills the process!
```

This means that any unsent data in the output buffer will not be sent.

If you instead don't wish the process to end then you need to use conditional logic.

```
<div>
<?php
if (strlen($string) < 6){   
    echo "minimum 6"
}
else if (strlen($string) > 32){   
    echo "maximum 32"
}   
else {
    echo "success"
}
?>
</div>
```